# WPF DataGrid ColumnHeaders Scroll Out of Sync with Data Cells

Tags: wpf, datagrid, horizontal-scrolling, scrollviewer, columnheader

The ColumnHeaders of my WPF DataGrid get out of sync with the data cells when scrolling horizontally.  It appears that the Columnheaders scroll faster than the data cells.  Vertical scrolling is workig ok. This is the View, which sizes the width of the DataGrid according to the Window size:

```
<Window.DataContext>
<vm:DemoDgViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid x:Name="dGrid" Height="300" Margin="15,0,15,0" Background="AliceBlue" Width="1000">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="32"/>
<RowDefinition Height="32"/>
<RowDefinition Height="32"/>
<RowDefinition Height="32"/>
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <DataGrid x:Name="demoDG" Width="{Binding Path=Width,
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path = DataContext.AppDataLcv, 
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType= 
 {x:Type Window}}}"  Style ="{DynamicResource StDataGrid2}"
 Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" Height="300" AlternationCount ="2"
 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode ="Single" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserSortColumns ="True"
 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ColumnWidth="Auto">

<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="desciption" SortMemberPath="desc"
 Binding ="{Binding Path=desc}" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserSort="True" 
 Width ="200">

 <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
 <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
 <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
 </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
 <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
 <Style TargetType="TextBox">
 <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
 </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>

 <!-- column 2, 3, 4, 5 same as the first --> 
 </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
 </Grid>
```

And this is the DataGrid style:

```
 <!-- DataGrid Styles ============ -->
 <Style x:Key="StDataGrid2" TargetType="DataGrid"  >

 <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
 <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="32" />
 <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="PowderBlue" />
 <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
 <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
 <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"  Value="True" />
 <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
 <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
 <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value ="{DynamicResource stDghdr}" />
 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0" />
 <Setter Property="Template">
 <Setter.Value >
 <ControlTemplate >
 <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF60727B">
 <DockPanel Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
  FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
  <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="15" Orientation="Horizontal"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" Width="200" >
  <RepeatButton x:Name="LineLeftButton" Width="90" Content="&lt;"
  Interval="1000" Delay="1000"
  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"
  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=dgscrollviewer}"ClickMode="Hover" />

  <RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" Width="90" Content="&gt;"
  Interval="1000" Delay="1000"
  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"
  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=dgscrollviewer}" ClickMode="Hover"/>
  </StackPanel>

  <ScrollViewer x:Name="dgscrollviewer" CanContentScroll ="True" 
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  CanHorizontallyScroll="True">

  <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
  FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height= "32" Padding="0" Margin="0" />

 <ItemsPresenter Height="300"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
 </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
 </DockPanel>
 </Border>
 </ControlTemplate>
 </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
 </Style>

 <Style x:Key="stDghdr" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader"  >
 <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value ="Stretch"/>
 <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
 <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="#79858b" />
 <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,5,0" />
 <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
 <Setter Property="Background" Value ="LavenderBlush"/>
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF60727B"/>
 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
 </Style>
```

Here is a link to download the demo:
[Demo](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsJLiAwJyR_VaKBzClvuT_zjW-I)

*Edit/ Update:  I think the ColumnHeaders are scrolling faster because they are controlled by a different ScrollViewer?  For instance, if I set a large FontSize property on the ScrollViewer that is in the DataGrid style, the text in the DataGrid cells gets bigger but not the text in the ColumnHeaders.

Any ideas or suggestions besides creating a ControlTemplate for the entire DataGrid?  Thank you.

Comment: I just downloaded your Demo and started using Visual Studio 2017. And I can't see any horizontall scroller. Please see my screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/248hr0200skcb7k/Screenshot%202017-06-24%2010.21.35.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,  the horizontal scrolling buttons  <  and > are on the row above the ColumnHeaders.

Comment: I clicked on them, but nothing happened.

Comment: It should work on hover

Comment: In the demo, resize the Window to narrow its width and then hover over the  buttons.

Comment: OK, now I can see it. In your question you should include steps to reproduce your issue. And include this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rchcokyr1hw1a7b/Screenshot%202017-06-25%2006.28.29__2.png?dl=0